# Error al intentar crear dos tablas con una relación 1-1

Tags: sql, transact-sql

Estoy tratando de crear dos tablas, `Estudiante`(Student) y `Carrera`(Course)
Estas dos tablas tiene una relación uno a uno, ya que un estudiante solo puede estudiar una carrera

El SQL MMS me está marcando error en la última linea, pero no entiendo el motivo.

```sql
CREATE TABLE Student
(
    student_id INT IDENTITY,
    name VARCHAR(20),
        CONSTRAINT PK_STUDENT_ID PRIMARY KEY (student_id)
)

CREATE TABLE Course
(
    course_id INT IDENTITY NOT NULL,
    stundent_id INT NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,

        CONSTRAINT PK_COURSE_ID PRIMARY KEY (course_id),
        CONSTRAINT FK_COURSE_STUDENT UNIQUE FOREIGN KEY (student_id)
)
```

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 15

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FOREIGN'.

> Completion time: 2022-05-30T12:56:07.0365028-04:00

Comment: `UNIQUE` foreign key?, no creo que eso exista. Por otro lado, falta la referencia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hola que tal para que no te marque error deberias de hacerlo de esta forma

```
CREATE TABLE Student
(
    student_id INT IDENTITY,
    name VARCHAR(20),
        CONSTRAINT PK_STUDENT_ID PRIMARY KEY (student_id)
)

CREATE TABLE Course
(
    course_id INT IDENTITY NOT NULL,
    stundent_id INT NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,

        CONSTRAINT PK_COURSE_ID PRIMARY KEY (course_id),
        CONSTRAINT FK_COURSE_STUDENT FOREIGN KEY (stundent_id)
    REFERENCES Student(student_id)
)
```

Te explico que tenias mal

```
CONSTRAINT FK_COURSE_STUDENT UNIQUE FOREIGN KEY (student_id)
```

No le indicabas de que tabla hace referencia y el unique esta de mas.

Con lo que te agregue se resuelve sin embargo no es correcta tu tabla ya que estas indicando que siempre que registres una carrera va ligada a un usuario lo correcto seria crear solo la tabla curso y una tabla mas donde asignes el usuarioid y el cursoid

Te anexo un ejemplo en esta url

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a7e5f353e9ab4239afc39fb76c7a009c

Ahi podras ver que una persona puede tener el mismo curso, por que de otra forma estas diciendo que un curso solo lo puede tener una persona.

Saludos

Comment: Una pregunta, si no declaro `UNIQUE` va a hacer una relacion de uno a muchos, por ese motivo estoy declarando el `UNIQUE` esto está mal ?

Comment: Si es unique si funciona como quieres pero no se pone en esa clausula, que necesitas? con lo que te dije el alumno ya esta en una carrera si quieras que no pueda estar en mas de una puedes agregar el unique pero a la tabla intermedia que te dije que hay que creear.
Te anexo la url para que veas esa funcionalidad https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=922450a7aef7434bdf2ea77cfd57a16b

Comment: Oye, es mi primer script en SQL estoy tratando de entender jejeje
https://ibb.co/2t76cqG  Tu diagrama relacion muchos muchos.

Es que los ejemplos que he visto no crean una tabla intermedia, por eso estoy confundido, osea asi tenga una relacion 1-1 ó 1-muchos, la forma correcta es crear una tabla intermedia?

Esto se hace para mejorar el rendimiento de la consulta ?

Comment: Mira te explico el por que de una tabla intermedia, si tu hacias lo que antes siempre que des de alta una carrera ya no ibas a poder crear otra igual por como dices solo va de uno a 1 es decir si la carrera DBA ID 1 la tiene edgar la misma carrera no la puede tener Jose por ejemplo por, en cambio asi como te digo creas la carrera y haces una tabla intermedia para que sea mejor el entendimiento igual te puede ayudar para saber cuantos alumnas tienes por carrera etc y solo manejas id

Ya no ibas a poder poner otro ID 1 DBA en esa tabla por que ya lo tenias asignado, no se si ya me explique?

Comment: A que te refieres con dar de alta? asignar? Creo que ya entendi el motivo de la tabla intermedia, hice el ejemplo en excel https://ibb.co/NTZjVV6 y me di cuenta que no puedo seguir registrando mas estudiantes a la tabla carrera ya que duplicaria el campo carrera es así verdad? confirmame porfa :)
Oye una pregunta que libro me recomendarias para aprender t-sql ?

Comment: Exactamente asi es, ya no podrias registrar la carrera para otro, que bueno que le entendiste, para empezar te recomendaria este t-sql fundamentals buscalo asi, saludos

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136703/discussion-between-im-newbie-and-edgar-vazquez).